# `kube-dns` gets wrong endpoint address with flannel causes POD DNS service failed

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I setup a 3 nodes kubernetes (`v1.9.3`) cluster on Ubuntu 16.04.

Prior setup I cleared the iptables rules and follow k8s documents for flannel with following command to initialize the cluster:

```
# kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.56.20 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --kubernetes-version 1.9.3
# kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.10.0/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

The previous command seemed successful:

```
# kubectl -n kube-system -n kube-system get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
etcd-master                      1/1       Running   0          3m
kube-apiserver-master            1/1       Running   0          2m
kube-controller-manager-master   1/1       Running   0          2m
kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-4c76v         3/3       Running   0          3m
kube-flannel-ds-wbx97            1/1       Running   0          1m
kube-proxy-x65lv                 1/1       Running   0          3m
kube-scheduler-master            1/1       Running   0          2m
```

But the problem is `kube-dns` seems got wrong service endpoint address assigned, this can be seen with following commands:

```
# kubectl get ep kube-dns --namespace=kube-system            
NAME       ENDPOINTS                     AGE
kube-dns   172.17.0.2:53,172.17.0.2:53   3m
root@master:~# kubectl describe service kube-dns -n kube-system           
Name:              kube-dns
Namespace:         kube-system
Labels:            k8s-app=kube-dns
                   kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
                   kubernetes.io/name=KubeDNS
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          k8s-app=kube-dns
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.96.0.10
Port:              dns  53/UDP
TargetPort:        53/UDP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.2:53
Port:              dns-tcp  53/TCP
TargetPort:        53/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.2:53
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

The `172.17.0.2` is the IP address assigned by docker bridge (`docker0`) for `kube-dns` container. On working k8s network setup, the `kube-dns` should have endpoints with address from `podSubnet` (`10.244.0.0/16`).

The effect of current setup is all the pods will not have functioned DNS while IP communication is ok.

I tried to delete `kube-dns` pod to see the new `kube-dns` containers can pick up the endpoints from `podSubnet` but they don't.

From the startup logs of 3 `kube-dns` containers, there are no ANY error messages.

Comment: Could you run `kubectl describe pod kube-dns -n kube-system` and provide us the results.

Comment: Did you enable bridging traffic to iptables?  Try `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` to see if it is enabled.

Comment: Yes, the `describe` is normal. And the `sysctl` settings are all done according to document.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found out the root cause for this. It is the previous `kubeadm reset` did not remove both `cni` and `flannel.1` interfaces. So the next `kubeadm init` makes `kube-dns` believes the Kubernetes network plugin is already in place before I apply the flannel yaml.

After I check and remove any virtual NICs created by flannel plugin when tearing down kubernetes cluster, the next `kubeadm init` can succeed without this issue any more.

The same thing applies to *Weave Net* that requires to run `weave reset` to remove remained virtual weave NICs.